# how to log to file?

Tags: android, logging

I would like to save some logs of my android app to an internal storage file (**not** SD).

This file should be limited by size and be cyclic (to get oldest information).

Looking at the internet, i can see the logback and Log4j, but the Log4j seems no longer in development and i am not sure about Logback quality.

What is the best way? A source code would be very helpful

[Lockback](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use Log4j2

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.3'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.3'
}
```

please refer this [log4j2-android](https://github.com/loune/log4j2-android)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Have you used it? I am a bit worried it is unstable, as i understand it is no longer in development.

Comment: log4j is truly no longer in development, but a new log framework named log4j2 which is used to instead of log4j is still in development.Please see here, https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/commits/master, Last commit was 19 hours ago